# Always point to north compass

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am able to make Compass through implementing a [tutorial here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rexc8O_IToY). Here is the code which is working perfectly.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

/// <summary>
/// 2d GUI Compass
/// </summary>
public class CompassWithDirectionMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    #region Vars

    public Transform player;
    public Texture compBg;
    public Texture blipTex;

    #endregion Vars

    #region UnityEvents

    void OnGUI()
    {
        //GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(0, 0, 120, 120), compBg);
        //GUI.DrawTexture(CreateBlip(), blipTex);

        GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(0, 0, 120, 120), compBg);
        GUI.DrawTexture(CreateBlip(), blipTex);

    }

    #endregion UnityEvents

    #region CustomMethods

    Rect CreateBlip()
    {
        //calculating player's angle
        Debug.Log("Player LocalEulerY" + player.eulerAngles.y);
        float angDeg = player.eulerAngles.y - 90;//bliper goes on Top
        float angRed = angDeg * Mathf.Deg2Rad;//Convert degree to radian;

        Debug.Log("Mathf.Cos(angRed) : "+ Mathf.Cos(angRed));
        Debug.Log("Mathf.Sin(angRed) : "+ Mathf.Sin(angRed));

        //calclulate blipper postion
        float blipX = 25 * Mathf.Cos(angRed);//25 pixel from center
        float blipY = 25 * Mathf.Sin(angRed);

        Debug.Log("blipX : "+ blipX);
        Debug.Log("blipY : "+ blipY);

        blipX += 55;//half of the size of the background of compass which is center and slight minus it
        blipY += 55;//

        Debug.Log("blipX : "+ blipX);
        Debug.Log("blipY : "+ blipY);

        return new Rect(blipX, blipY, 10, 10);
    }

    #endregion CustomMethods
}
```

I want to change bliptex with arrow but its not working correctly. loosing the center of the compass image.
[image]

Comment: And where is the code that isn't working perfectly?

Comment: I'd advise you to use the Unity UI system instead of `OnGUI()` (this method should be used for debug only since it's really heavy to run (called multiple times per frame)). Also doing it with Unity UI you'll simply have to place your background somewhere, set the blipper as child and finally affect the blipper `RectTransform.localEulerAngle.z` value :)

Comment: In any case, you might want to get rid of the magic numbers. Create some constant variables like centerX and centerY and use those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set size of rect in

```
GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(0, 0, 120, 120), compBg);
```

and set center position accordingly in

```
blipX += 55;
blipY += 55;
```

I assume 120 and 55 are values based size of the texture he is using, as you are using a different texture you need to set size of the texture appropriately.

Hope this helps

Comment: I have change blipX +=10 and blipy +=10 to now it in center but it rotating complete object not rotating from bottom of the arrow