# Setting North in GUI

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Camera Player in a scene. 3D Scene with 2d Compass GUI. Scene contains a fixed north which i want to indicate on my compass with needle but how can i do it?
 I tried this code using a [**Tutorial**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=urNuYkkbZCc) so far but my needle movement direction is not appropriate according to my north.

```
   public void ChangeNortDirection() {

        northDirection.z = player.eulerAngles.y;
        northLayer.localEulerAngles = northDirection;

    }
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the compass? Is it pointing towards the wrong direction or not rotating at all?

Comment: it is rotating but its direction is wrong. It is not pointing to correct north

Comment: Is this fixed north a GameObject in the scene or do you have some map layout where you want to have a specific point as north?

Comment: Specific direction towards north, not so much precise

Comment: I'd suggest creating a Vector3 named north that represents a line towards the precise north direction, for example my north would be Vector3(0,0,1); so my north will be straight forward on the Z. Then use the Y rotation of your character as offset. So you can rotate the compass pointer with that offset.

Comment: . Then use the Y rotation of your character as offset. So you can rotate the compass pointer with that offset. ?

Comment: Make sure to accept one of the answers or add comment(s) if you don't find the answers solving your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the tutorial and seeing what you did I came up with an idea.

The only problem you have is that the pointer is not looking at north but at something else while it is still rotating with the character.

In your case you can easily add one simple value that adds up to the compass pointer's initial state.
The compass pointer will still rotate with your characters Y rotation but the compass pointer will point to a different direction than it normally would.

```
public float extraOffset; /* Edit this inside the editor on playmode until 
your pointer points towards your north.
Then remember that value and set it while you are not in playmode.*/
public void ChangeNortDirection() {

    northDirection.z = extraOffset + player.eulerAngles.y; // Just added the simple extraoffset variable and you are good to go.
    northLayer.localEulerAngles = northDirection;

}
```

Also remember to explain your question as good as possible since it can be really hard for us to know what the exact problem is.
For example tell us if your game is going to be 2D or 3D and what the initial idea behind the subject of the problem is.

Hope this helps you out a bit.

- Mennolp

Comment: i will try it through adding offset but FYI I have already did it with by subtracting the offset. The problem is that as i start to rotate my player from north to west my needle direction moves opposite.

Comment: Anyhow i will try it with positive offset

Comment: it shouldn't really matter if the offset is negative or positive as long as the north is good at initial start but try this to reverse the pointer rotation: northDirection.z = -(extraOffset + player.eulerAngles.y);

Comment: Thanks i have also tried it through multiplying -1. but i will check it again.

Comment: one more thing. did you read the answer of Joe Mccane. he saying something conversely which creates much confusion?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the north direction to the y axis of the player, so if the player rotates so does the north direction.

What you want to do is have a variable indicating the absolute north direction and then just rotate the compass in the opposite direction the player has rotated.

Another thing is, is this in 2D or 3D space? In 2D you only want to rotate the z axis at all times and not touch the x and y axis. And in 3D the north direction should be defined in only the z axis so that only the x and y plane rotates.

For a definitive answer please provide more information.

Comment: I am much confuse to follow it. As my scene has a fixed north and i just want to show a compass that point towards north

Comment: its only 2D shape as you can see the image in question

Answer (score 0):

I guess your question is related to the previous one : that's nice to see you're using Unity UI system now (but you could have given people over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41482141/always-point-to-north-compass) a bit of feedback to their answers/comments) !

Regarding your current question, one of the best (and simplest) solution is to get your player's forward transform (blue axis in scene view) and to used it's X an Z values (Y doesn't matter here) to get the angle you want :

`northLayer.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, Mathf.Atan2(player.forward.x, player.forward.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg);`

This example is considering your `northDirection` vector is 0,0,1 and your `northLayer` is pointing north when its `localEulerAngles.z` is set to 0 (and of course that `northLayer` is a *RectTransform* component).

Hope this helps,